# Node-sass, using Parallel-shell, not watching

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, node-sass

I am compiling my sass using `node-sass` via `npm scripts` running in parallel with other compilation tasks, using `parallelshell`.

I noticed that node-sass has a `--watch` option, but it does not compile the sass first before watching. So I first run node-sass with `--watch`, and then again without.

This works in the CLI, but does not work in parallelshell.

---

The sass task:

```
"sass": "node-sass src/scss/ -o build/stylesheets/ -r --output-style=expanded"
```

This works:

```
npm run sass && npm run sass -- --watch
```

This also works:

```
parallelshell 'npm run sass' 'npm run sass -- --watch'
```

This does not work:

```
parallelshell 'npm run sass && npm run sass -- --watch'
```

---

No errors are reported, the task just ends and doesn't watch the files.

Can anyone shed light as to why the last task does not work?

Comment: It seems parallelshell is deprecated... and [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/) looks to have fixed this issue.